# blast.js changing position of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `h1` and a `nav` with a `ul` and `li`s. When the mouse goes over the `h1` the `h1` animates and the `li` fades in. However the list is not where it is supposed to be after the animation. Originally the list is centered in the header with `display:inline` but after the animation the list is stuck in the left top corner and seems to have a result similar to `display:block` Why does this happen?

[JSbin](https://jsbin.com/tosemeyehe/edit?html,output)

```
$('h1').one('mouseover', function () {

$('h1').blast({
  delimiter: 'word',
  generateValueClass: true
});

  $('.blast-word-surviving')
  .css({
    position: 'relative',
    left: 0
  })
  .animate({left: '-100vw' }, 1600);
  setTimeout(function() {
      $('.blast-word-surviving').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $('nav').css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('li').velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 1500 });
  }, 2000);

$('.blast-word-earth')
.css({
  position: 'relative',
  left: 0
})
.animate({left: '100vw' }, 1600);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.blast-word-earth').css('visibility', 'hidden');
     $('nav').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('li').velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 1500 });
}, 2000);


});
```

Comment: Post some code in your post, just link to code are not well received on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your animation library changes your `li` `display:inline` to `display: list-item` like it should be by default. Try to add following code:

```
li {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

It should keep your list items inline even if library changes element inline styles.

Comment: the inline is working but now the list appears underneath the nav, I tried giving it a - top margin with !important and using line-height and neither worked